# If elapsed time is longer than 24 hours then

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement, time, strtotime

Edit: This problem is solved, I used Marc B's answer in the comments.

I calculated the elapsed time and I want to echo it with red font if it's longer than 24 hours. This works if its 24:00:00 but if it turns 25:00:00 it doesn't echo it in red anymore.

How can I fix this?

This is what I have done:

1. I take the timestamp from the Status table, this is in timestamp
   format.
2. Then I get the current time from the database.
3. I do `strtotime()` for both values to assure they have the same
   format.
4. I subtract the Status time from current time so I get the elapsed time.
5. Then I check if the elapsed time is bigger than 24 hours.

Code:

```
$timestamp = $status_row['Time'];

$sql_time_difference    = "SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '$timestamp') as TimeDiff";
//echo $sql_time_difference;
$time_select            = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_time_difference);
$time_row               = mysqli_fetch_assoc($time_select);    
$time_difference        = $time_row['TimeDiff'];

//echo $time_difference.'<br>';

$time1  = strtotime($time_difference);
$time2  = strtotime('24:00:00'); 

if ($time_difference >= $time2){
    echo '<b><font color="red">'.$time_difference.'</font></b>';    
} else {
    echo $time_difference; 
}
```

Comment: why are you using mysql for this at all? There is absolutely **ZERO** point in roundtripping a time value through mysql just to do some date math. You can TRIVIALLY do this in php, e.g. `if (strtotime($timestamp) + 60*60*24 <= time())`

Comment: @MarcB because im not sure how time in php works, its quite confusing to me. But thank you for your answer, im gonna try this.

Comment: One of the first things I learned in PHP was that a day is 86400 seconds

Comment: Use ` TIMESTAMPDIFF`

Comment: is the time you get from the web server and the time you get from the database always the same?

Comment: ask the guy below; they gave you an "answer". let them work for it.

Answer (score 0):

> you said that code turns 25:00:00 but color is not red

so try this:

```
echo '<b style="color: #f00;">'.$time_difference.'</b>';
```

Comment: that isn't what the question is about. Both OP's and your code, give the same result. `<font>` is deprecated, but it still works. I know, I tested both. Deprecated does not mean "deleted".